# Neo4j "Sandbox" Error while I import CSV file

Tags: neo4j

I have referred to "how to import csv data in neo4j DB". However, all of them refer the standalone DB.
      I created a Blank Sandbox on neo4j browser (not standalone) and trying to import from the local Windows machine with the guidelines given in Neo4j documentation as below.

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:C:/San/MyGraphData_CSV.csv' as row
RETURN row.columName;

I get Error " Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError: URI is not hierarchical
".

The solutions earlier recommended to replace C:/ with C:/// and other, seems to refer the Standby Neo4j. But i am using online Sandbox and importing.
Please help me resolve as this is POC and I need to evaluate more features and go for the concrete neo4j installation

Regards
San

Comment: However I am able to load the example given in neo4j documentation.
LOAD CSV FROM 'https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.3/csv/artists.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Artist { name: line[1], year: toInteger(line[2])})

Answer (score 0):

File URIs should begin with "file:///".

*The 3 slashes do not go after the Windows drive letter.*

Comment: Yea.. I meant the File protocol. i tried the same way which you replied for. But the same issue. Anyways, i managed for a standby neo4j and not the sandbox. Thank you